# Resizing raw images with PHP Imagick isn't working

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, codeigniter-3, imagick, rawimage

After multiple attempts, I was able to install ImageMagick and PHP Imagick extension.  However, it fails to create Imagick object itself.  Unfortunately, no error/ exception is shown anywhere.

My development environment is -

```
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/7.0.10
CodeIgniter 3.0.3
imagick 3.4.3 (compiled with ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27)
ImageMagick-7.0.8-61-Q16-x64-dll.exe

MAGICK_HOME and PATH variables are set correctly
```

`magick` and `convert` commands on command line are working fine.

The output of below test is **Yes**

```
<?php
echo extension_loaded('imagick') && class_exists('Imagick') ? 'Yes' : 'No', PHP_EOL;
```

The output of below test is resulting in ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

```
try {
    $im = new Imagick('c:/IMG_2935.jpg'); OR

    $im = new Imagick('c:/IMG_2935.cr2'); OR

    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImage('C:/e35455e32c684bc70d187418d95b9eb7.CR2');


} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    print_r($e, true);
}
```

Pls help..

TIA

Comment: Why not start with something simple; file and image all in the same folder? As you are on windows try " instead of ' in your commands.

Comment: Your PHP Imagick and ImageMagick versions differ...

Comment: Your Imagick says compiled with IM 6, but your ImageMagick says IM 7. So there is likely a conflict. Perhaps install ImageMagick 6 rather than ImageMagick 7.

Comment: @Bonzo, no luck with moving files to default locations.  

Imw42, I tried with ImageMagick 6.9.3-10 & 6.9.10.  There's not much progress.  I'm planning to switch to linux or GMagick.  I'll update the progress.  Thanks for the responses..

Comment: @MarkSetchell I even made it so that doing that triggers a warning...it wasn't enough obviously.